# Queries on Schengen Visa application

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, spain, netherlands

I am an Indian national on student (F1) visa in USA. I will be travelling to two Schengen countries for different reasons but in a very small time frame:

- I have a interview in Amsterdam, Netherlands on March 9th, 2017 and the company requires me to fly to Amsterdam on a day before and leave a day after. They have said that I should apply for "Short Stay Business Schengen Visa".
- I am also travelling to Barcelona, Spain on March 13, 2017 for pleasure.

What are my best options for visa application? Can I apply for one visa and visit both countries? If not, any suggestions how both can be accomplished?

Comment: Definitely, apply for one visa. Which country is your longest stay there you should apply for a visa. It doesn't matter if you enter or leave through another country in Schengen.

Answer (score 4):

Apply to the Netherlands for one visa covering both trips.  If they decide to grant the visa for just the Netherlands trip, you can then apply to Spain for a visa to cover the Barcelona trip.

I suggest applying to the Netherlands because the job interview arguably makes the Netherlands your main destination when considering the two trips together.  However, if you are spending several days in Barcelona, they may decide that Spain should be considered the main destination.  In that case, they should reject the application with a suggestion that you apply to Spain for a visa to cover both trips, in which case you should of course do that.